# insert formula in column until next non blank cell

Tags: excel, reference, cell, vba

In my macro, i need to insert a formula in columns AA and AB, AB is empty so no problem there. Column AA has data which starts in AA10954, my problem is AA10954 changes each week as my data either increases or decrease as i import from another book, can someone help me to set the last empty cell before my data starts in AA?

Sub ClassVisit()
    '
    ' ClassVisit Macro
    '
    '

Dim lr As Long

```
    With ActiveWorkbook

    With ActiveSheet

    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("AA2").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,[Data.xlsb]Stores!$A:$AA,27,0),VLOOKUP(A2,'[Salesinfo.xlsb]Packs'!$C:$E,3,0))"

    Range("AB2:AB" & lr).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Attribute!D:F,3,0),""Not Visited"")"

Range("AA2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A10953")
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A10953").Select

    Range("AA2:AB" & lr).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -26).Range("A1").Select
   End With
 End With
End Sub
```